# The category description is duplicated after migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2.4.2-p1

Tags: category-description

```
    Magento 2.4.2-p1 migrated from Magento 1.9.4 via the Migration tool
    Porto theme
We recently had Amasty install extensions for us. I don't know if this issue was on there before or not.
```

We have recently migrated all of our data from Magento 1.9.4 using the Magento Migration Tool. Now, when I open any category - the category description appears twice - once at the top and then again right below at the top of the body (where the products are listed below). This is happening to all categories.

**I don't mind deleting the duplication manually but I can't find where to do that?** When I load a category up to and go through all the fields - the only place I see this text is in the Description and when I click to 'Edit with Page Builder' - it only shows the text once!

Removing everything from within the Page Builder window under Description removes both texts (there is no text on the category page then, just products). When I put the text back into the Description of the category, it appears twice again.

---

UPDATED later on August 12th:

**I was able to fix this by following these steps**:

```
Porto --> Settings Panel --> Category View --> change Category Description Position to 'Default'
```

*Both 'As Full Width below the Header' and 'Main Column above the Toolbar' create the duplicate Description problem!* *Would anyone know why that is and how to fix it?*

Comment: its twice on frontend only?

Comment: Yes - twice on front-end only!

Comment: then all good with migration. but may be you calling twice on frontend only. please check frontend code. $product->getDescription may be calling twice.